# Relative path in absolute URI: txt Spark mac

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running Spark on **Mac** (jupyter notebook) and not **Windows**. I am trying to read a txt file:

```
val text = sc.textFile("shakespeare.txt")
val relevant_lines = text.filter(l => l.contains("Music"))
val result = relevant_lines.count()
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: Module 3:%20Apache%20Spark
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:93)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:211)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1676)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:259)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1168)
  ... 37 elided
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: Module 3:%20Apache%20Spark
  at java.base/java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1941)
  at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:757)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:202)
  ... 61 more
```

Could you help me fix it?

Thank you

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, don't you think? - You have to pass an absolute path, also it is trying to load a file from **HDFS** & I am sure you want to read a local file instead, use `val text = sc.textFile("file:///pat/to/your/file/shakespeare.txt")`.

Comment: Dear Luis, I already tried it and it does not work

Comment: I also tried: `val text = sc.textFile("file:///Users/berradam/Desktop/Columbia/Analytics on the cloud/Module 3: Apache Spark/shakespeare.txt")`

Comment: And it produced the same error? - Have you tried with a path without white spaces? _(I do not believe that is the problem, but you do not lose anything trying)_. Also, please update your question with every attempt and their results.

Answer (score 0):

```
Give the complete path where the text file is located in your MAC.
eg -: "/user/name/shakespeare.txt" 

For multiple text files 
Syntax-: sc.textFile("/user/name/*")

val text = sc.textFile("/user/name/shakespeare.txt")
val relevant_lines = text.filter(l => l.contains("Music"))
val result = relevant_lines.count()
```